# Assign Global Variable/Argument for Any Build to Use

Tags: build, tfs, build-process, tfsbuild

I have several (15 or so) builds which all reference the same string of text in their respective build process templates. Every 90 days that text expires and needs to be updated in each of the templates. Is there a way to create a central variable or argument

Comment: It's mind-boggling that Microsoft thought it would be OK not to include these in TFS. I'm using v2017 and still does not have them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to create an environment variable on your build machine. Then reference the variable in all of your builds. When you needed to update the value you would only have to set it in one place.

[How to: Use Environment Variables in a Build](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms171459%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

If you have more than one build machine then it could become too much of a maintenance issue.

Another solution would involve using [MSBuild response files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfs/ms404301.aspx). You create an .rsp file that holds the property value and the value would be picked up and set from MSBuild via the command line.

Comment: I like the idea of the environment variable. These particular builds must be handled by a specific build machine, so that would be fine.

Comment: All environment variables are available to the Microsoft Build Engine (MSBuild) project file as properties and since TFS takes your solution file and hands it off to msbuild all you have to do is create a property in your project or solution files and set it with the environment variable syntax...i.e $(Name_of_Property). It makes it really easy.

Comment: Take a look at this link as well...http://lajak.wordpress.com/2011/03/13/pass-relative-path-arguments-to-msbuild-in-tfs2010-team-build/

Comment: Where are you setting the property MyTxt? You have to set the property MyTxt to some value either in the MSBuild.rsp file or via the build definition msbuild arguments. i.e /p:MyTxt="Some Txt". You only have to set it in one place in the rsp file. As long as you create this property in your build process template. It will get set from the .rsp file or if you choose to pass it in via the Msbuild arguments in the build definition. I wish I could see what you have done. It should not be this hard.

Comment: Thanks, SoftwareCarpenter. Here's how I did it: 
1.) On the build machine, I created an environment variable called MyTxt and gave it a value of "Hello World".
2.) On the build process template, I created a variable called MyTxt and gave it a default value of Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MyTxt").
3.) Then, to confirm, I added a write build message activity and assigned the MyTxt variable to the message property. 

I queued up a new build and I'm seeing "Hello World" now. :)

Comment: I appreciate your patience and help. I've marked your initial response as the answer. I'm also going to cleanup the comments for anyone else that might find this Q/A useful.

Comment: Awesome! I will clean up comments as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to place it into somewhere where all your builds can access it, then customize your build process template to read from there (build definitions - as you know - do not have a mechanism to share data between defs).

Some examples would be a file checked into TFS, a file in a known location (file share), web page, web service, etc.

You could even make a custom activity that knew how to read it and output the result as an OutArgument (e.g. Custom activity that read the string from a hardcoded URL).

Comment: File located under custom assemblies directory is a good place, this is stored in tfs under source control and is updated if it changes by build controler, location is available for build from BuildEnvironment variable (you can get this object from activity context extensions as well)